# Problems after installing Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

Since the last Windows 10 update I can't install Chrome extensions in Opera and my God Mode vanished. I tried a Windows reset but nothing helped. I reinstalled everything as before.  Even my camera does not work in the Skype App and it says that it is in use with Skype. Everything is very strange.

I use Windows 10 version 1703, Build 15063.296

I think it is maybe a program which causes all this trouble. I use Malwarebytes Antiransom Beta and Kaspersky. But I use them already for a long time.

Comment: what happens when you try to install chrome extensions?

Comment: Everything as usual. It installs the extension. But there should be also the **Add to Opera** which is still missing. The problem with the Skype App is solved and wasn't connected to this problem. Yesterday I tried the hardware troubleshooter and it installed drivers which weren't there before. I'm not very happy about it and now I don't know how to get rid of this change. The **GodMode** still doesn't work yet.

Comment: godmode was always carp, only access to all control panel entries. control panel gets reduced in each new Windows10 build before it gets removed completely later

Comment: Found a way to make **GodMode** work and I think I need to uninstall Chrome completely to make the Opera extensions work again. When I tried doing so, it said to close windows 8 mode windows. How do I do this and uninstall chrome completely to reinstall a fresh version?

Answer (score 0):

I also had side effects (crashes) with GodMode and some java applications.
The crashes occured when a file open dialog should be opened.
When I deleted that GodMode Folder with the magic name 
.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
from my desktop the crashes disappeared.

I could also reproduce the crashes putting that GodMode Folder in another
folder than ...\Desktop, then the crash occured later when selecting that folder in a file open dialog.